# Im getting error while parsing JSON Object. My code on server is in asp.net and it returns only two values. My java code is below

Tags: android, json, parsing

This is my main Activity :-

```
package com.example.shafqatsk.android_php_sql;

 import org.json.JSONArray; import org.json.JSONException; import
 org.json.JSONObject; import android.os.AsyncTask; import
 android.os.Bundle; import android.app.Activity; import
 android.view.Menu; import android.widget.TextView;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     JSONObject jobj = null;
     ServiceHandler sv = new ServiceHandler();
     TextView itemName, itemColor, itemPrice;
     String ab;
     JSONArray jsonArray;
     JSONObject jsonObject;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         itemName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         itemColor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);


         //start background processing
         new RetreiveData().execute();
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
         return true;
     }
     class RetreiveData extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

         @Override
         protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             jobj = sv.makeHttpRequest("http://192.168.1.253/StockService.asmx/GetItemData");

             try {
                 //jsonArray = jobj.getJSONArray(arg0[0]);
                 ab = jobj.getString("ItemName");
                 ab += jobj.getString("ItemId");
             } catch (JSONException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
             return ab;
         }
         protected void onPostExecute(String ab){
             itemName.append(ab);
         }
     } }
```

This is my service handler class :-

```
package com.example.shafqatsk.android_php_sql;

 import java.io.BufferedReader; import java.io.IOException; import
 java.io.InputStream; import java.io.InputStreamReader; import
 org.apache.http.HttpEntity; import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
 import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException; import
 org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost; import
 org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient; import
 org.json.JSONException; import org.json.JSONObject; /* this class
 helps to get data from server*/ public class ServiceHandler {
     //input stream deals with bytes
     static InputStream is = null;
     static JSONObject jobj = null;
     static String json = "";
     //constructor
     public ServiceHandler(){

     }
     //this method returns json object.
     public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url){ //http client helps to send and receive data
         DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); //our request method is post
         HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
         try { //get the response
             HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
             HttpEntity httpentity = httpresponse.getEntity(); // get the content and store it into inputstream object.
             is = httpentity.getContent();
         } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

         try { //convert byte-stream to character-stream.
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
             StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
             String line = null;
             try {
                 while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
                     sb.append(line+"\n");

                 } //close the input stream
                 is.close();
                 System.out.println("Result : "+sb.toString());
                 json = sb.toString();
                 try {
                     jobj = new JSONObject(json);
                 } catch (JSONException e) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }

         } catch (Exception e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return jobj;
     } }
```

Error in Logcat :-

```
05-19 02:10:42.336 9552-9589/com.example.shafqatsk.android_php_sql E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
                                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
                                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
                                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                         at com.example.shafqatsk.android_php_sql.MainActivity$RetreiveData.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:48)
                                                                                         at com.example.shafqatsk.android_php_sql.MainActivity$RetreiveData.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:39)
                                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
                                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080) 
                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573) 
                                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 
05-19 02:10:42.352 9552-9552/com.example.shafqatsk.android_php_sql E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
05-19 02:10:42.356 9552-9552/com.example.shafqatsk.android_php_sql E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
```

Comment: I see in your comments, that the request is post type, but where is the post data? what is the response JSON? can you share that, so we have a better idea of what may be the error.

Comment: Anyway guys I found the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What parameter you are passing in request if it is required ? if your web service type is post.

Instead of doing code for web call you can use loopj library http://loopj.com/android-async-http/ all exceptions are handled in this library. You will just need to pars your data form response using JSON key, you can get guide on the site. I hope this will help you.

Comment: If you have questions for the OP, the best place for those is in the comments. Answers should answer the question completely and in full where possible.

Answer (score 2):

I want to ask more detail but I haven't permission, so I write here.

Maybe your `jobj` is null

What's the output of  `System.out.println("Result : "+sb.toString());` ?

Comment: Hao Qi, Thanks for your reply. Actually i was passing the incorect url. And about the output i was getting was an html error 404 page. Thanks again sir.